# wpf / silverlight textbox filter design

Tags: wpf, user-interface, textbox, filter

I have a list that the user can filter in several ways. two of which lend themselves to combo boxes and two that need to accept user input. For example, one textbox allows the user to type in any part of a list item's description, and the dialog will only present items whose description contains the text entered.

It is a dialog 'picker' type of window, so space is at a premium. I'd like for the text boxes not to require a traditional label. Instead, when the dialog is first invoked, the label (ie, "Description") is grayed out, centered, and in italics. Maybe a tool tip to further make it obvious to the user what it's for. When the user starts to type, the faux label disappears and the entered text is normal left aligned text.

Does wpf / silverlight have any native support for doing something like this? I guess it could be a combination of styles and eventing. I'd rather not invent any wheels that might be out there (I got the idea specifically from looking at Tortoise' "Show Log" window, but I've seen it before).

Does anyone have any sample code they can share to do this? Or a an alternative idea that also saves space and simplifies the layout?

Cheers,
Berryl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin Moore's InfoTextBox, which is part of his [Bag-O-Tricks](http://j832.com/bagotricks/) is the kind of thing I was looking for, almost exactly. This is also the 'watermark' (great name - I would have found this sooner if I had known that) text box from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-textbox-in-wpf).