# WPF Watermark PasswordBox from Watermark TextBox

Tags: wpf, watermark, passwordbox

I am using a Watermark textbox as in [Watermark TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-textbox-in-wpf)

```
 <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBackground}" Style="{StaticResource EntryFieldStyle}" >
        <TextBlock Margin="5,2" Text="This prompt dissappears as you type..." Foreground="{StaticResource brushWatermarkForeground}"
                   Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtUserEntry, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <TextBox Name="txtUserEntry" Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBorder}" />
    </Grid>
```

How can I apply this for a PasswordBox?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The general approach is the same: write a custom control style, and show the watermark whenever the password box is empty. The only problem here is that `PasswordBox.Password` is not a dependency property, and you can't use it in a trigger. Also PasswordBox is sealed, so you can't override this notification behavior, but you can use attached properties here.

The following code demonstrates how.

XAML:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:WpfTest="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
    Title="Password Box Sample" Height="300" Width="300">
  <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="{x:Type PasswordBox}"
        TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
      <Setter Property="WpfTest:PasswordBoxMonitor.IsMonitoring"
              Value="True"/>
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type PasswordBox}">
            <Border Name="Bd"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
              <Grid>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                              SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Please enter your password" 
                           Margin="4, 2, 0, 0"
                           Foreground="Gray" 
                           Visibility="Collapsed"
                           Name="txtPrompt" />
              </Grid>
            </Border>
            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                         Value="false">
                <Setter TargetName="Bd"
                                            Property="Background"
                                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger Property="WpfTest:PasswordBoxMonitor.PasswordLength" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="txtPrompt" Value="Visible"/>
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <PasswordBox VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```cs
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfTest {
    public partial class Window1 : Window {
        public Window1() {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

  public class PasswordBoxMonitor : DependencyObject {
    public static bool GetIsMonitoring(DependencyObject obj) {
      return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsMonitoringProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsMonitoring(DependencyObject obj, bool value) {
      obj.SetValue(IsMonitoringProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsMonitoringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsMonitoring", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxMonitor), new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsMonitoringChanged));

    public static int GetPasswordLength(DependencyObject obj) {
      return (int)obj.GetValue(PasswordLengthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetPasswordLength(DependencyObject obj, int value) {
      obj.SetValue(PasswordLengthProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty PasswordLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("PasswordLength", typeof(int), typeof(PasswordBoxMonitor), new UIPropertyMetadata(0));

    private static void OnIsMonitoringChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
      var pb = d as PasswordBox;
      if (pb == null) {
        return;
      }
      if ((bool) e.NewValue) {
        pb.PasswordChanged += PasswordChanged;
      } else {
        pb.PasswordChanged -= PasswordChanged;
      }
    }

    static void PasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
      var pb = sender as PasswordBox;
      if (pb == null) {
        return;
      }
      SetPasswordLength(pb, pb.Password.Length);
    }
  }
}
```

Please notice `PasswordBoxMonitor` in XAML code.

Comment: Hi Although this post is quite old, but can you tell me please how to achieve this in windows phone 8? I have tried the above procedure but it seems that <ControlTemplate.Triggers> </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

 is not in there in Windows phone 8. How could I achieve if I want to build a windows phone 8 apps with textbox and Password box with watermark, please help.

Comment: Fast and simple solution. But it seems that it does **not** support the focus template.

Comment: What if you want to make another one that says "Re-enter Password" can you do that without having to re-write the entire style?

Answer (score 11):

you can show/hide the background by yourself instead of using triggers:

XAML:

```
<PasswordBox x:Name="passwordBox" PasswordChanged="passwordChanged" 
        Background="{StaticResource PasswordHint}" />
```

Code behind:

```
// helper to hide watermark hint in password field
private void passwordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{           
    if (passwordBox.Password.Length == 0)
        passwordBox.Background.Opacity = 1;
    else
        passwordBox.Background.Opacity = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution I can find, although it took some time for me to understand the Background property here. It would have been much better if there was a declaration for "PasswordHint" in the answer. However, Works very well... +1

Comment: I've edited this answer to include a reference to the StaticResource called PasswordHint. Worked for me, and simple.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments, you are missing explanation for *PasswordHint* thus making your answer incomplete

Answer (score 4):

you can use my approach for a watermark behavior. all you have to do is copy and paste the `TextBoxWatermarkBehavior` and the change the `Behavior<TextBox>` to `Behavior<PasswordBox>`.

you can find a demo project [here](http://blindmeis.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/wpf-watermark-textbox-behavior/)

Comment: It works very well. I thinks this should be the answer..Thanks

Comment: id guess so too, but do you have an english explanation as well? google translate isnt exactly the most acurate translator

Comment: @blindmeis, Thanks. Your suggestion worked for me. I have modified the TextBoxWatermarkBehavior class as you suggested and the final PasswordBoxWatermarkBehavior class, I have given it [as a seperate answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38518083/1977871)

Answer (score 0):

@blindmeis's [suggestion is good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3265372/1977871). For PasswordBox the class would be as follows.

```
public class PasswordBoxWatermarkBehavior : System.Windows.Interactivity.Behavior<PasswordBox>
{
    private TextBlockAdorner adorner;
    private WeakPropertyChangeNotifier notifier;

    #region DependencyProperty's

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Label", typeof(string), typeof(PasswordBoxWatermarkBehavior));

    public string Label
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelStyleProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("LabelStyle", typeof(Style), typeof(PasswordBoxWatermarkBehavior));

    public Style LabelStyle
    {
        get { return (Style)GetValue(LabelStyleProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelStyleProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += this.AssociatedObjectLoaded;
        this.AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged += AssociatedObjectPasswordChanged;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.Loaded -= this.AssociatedObjectLoaded;
        this.AssociatedObject.PasswordChanged -= this.AssociatedObjectPasswordChanged;

        this.notifier = null;
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectPasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateAdorner();
    }

    private void AssociatedObjectLoaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.adorner = new TextBlockAdorner(this.AssociatedObject, this.Label, this.LabelStyle);

        this.UpdateAdorner();

        //AddValueChanged for IsFocused in a weak manner
        this.notifier = new WeakPropertyChangeNotifier(this.AssociatedObject, UIElement.IsFocusedProperty);
        this.notifier.ValueChanged += new EventHandler(this.UpdateAdorner);
    }

    private void UpdateAdorner(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.UpdateAdorner();
    }


    private void UpdateAdorner()
    {
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.AssociatedObject.Password) || this.AssociatedObject.IsFocused)
        {
            // Hide the Watermark Label if the adorner layer is visible
            this.AssociatedObject.TryRemoveAdorners<TextBlockAdorner>();
        }
        else
        {
            // Show the Watermark Label if the adorner layer is visible
            this.AssociatedObject.TryAddAdorner<TextBlockAdorner>(adorner);
        }
    }
}
```