# How to create Search text box like the one in Expression blend?

Tags: wpf, blend

How to create search text box like the one in Expression blend? Is it existing control in WPF/Expression Blend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a WatermarkTextBox, it is [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-textbox-in-wpf).

Comment: Thanks, I found exactly what I was looking for in your link :-) well, it's not the watermark, but the search box
http://davidowens.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/wpf-search-text-box/