# Where is the IsEmpty reference/member in this XAML code?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I cannot understand where the `IsEmpty` comes from in this snippet of code (`Path=Text.IsEmpty`) (about a watermark TextBox):

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBackground}" 
                   Style="{StaticResource EntryFieldStyle}" >
    <TextBlock Margin="5,2" Text="Type to search ..." Foreground="Gray"
               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=entry, Path=Text.IsEmpty, 
                          Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
    <TextBox Name="entry" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

You can see a string does not have any `IsEmpty` property. A `DependencyProperty` also does not have any `IsEmpty` member. I've even tried searching the `IsEmpty` in the Object Browser window but there was not any relevant result explaining the code.

Could you explain to me the `IsEmpty` reference here? (Any reference link about it is great).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`IsEmpty` is being resolved from [CollectionView.IsEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.isempty(v=vs.110).aspx)

*how?*

I applied high tracing for the binding

```
Visibility="{Binding ElementName=entry,
                     PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High, 
                     Path=Text.IsEmpty, 
                     Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

and here is the result

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=40147308) for Binding (hash=39658150)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'Text.IsEmpty'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Default mode resolved to OneWay
System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Default update trigger resolved to PropertyChanged
System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Attach to System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.Visibility (hash=2939094)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 :     Lookup name entry:  queried TextBlock (hash=2939094)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Resolve source deferred
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Found data context element: <null> (OK)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 74 :     Lookup name entry:  queried TextBlock (hash=2939094)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 78 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Activate with root item TextBox (hash=46768536)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308):   At level 0 - for TextBox.Text found accessor DependencyProperty(Text)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Replace item at level 0 with TextBox (hash=46768536), using accessor DependencyProperty(Text)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): GetValue at level 0 from TextBox (hash=46768536) using DependencyProperty(Text): ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308):   At level 1 - for String.IsEmpty found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308):   At level 1 - for EnumerableCollectionView.IsEmpty found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEmpty)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): Replace item at level 1 with EnumerableCollectionView (hash=40847598), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEmpty)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): GetValue at level 1 from EnumerableCollectionView (hash=40847598) using RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEmpty): 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): TransferValue - got raw value 'True'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 82 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): TransferValue - user's converter produced 'Visible'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308): TransferValue - using final value 'Visible'
```

interesting lines from the above trace

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308):   At level 1 - for String.IsEmpty found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=40147308):   At level 1 - for EnumerableCollectionView.IsEmpty found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEmpty)
```

so you can see that indeed type `String` does not have `IsEmpty`

```
for String.IsEmpty found accessor <null>
```

but the view for the string is an `EnumerableCollectionView` which does have `IsEmpty` and the binding resolved to the same

```
for EnumerableCollectionView.IsEmpty found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(IsEmpty)
```

Comment: thanks. I know `string` is an IEnumerable (contains characters) but not know about the `CollectionView` created as the view behind the scene, this view does have `IsEmpty` property.

Comment: I did have the same perception till I saw your question. I knew that every collection has a view, but I am also amused to see that a basic type `string` (actually a collection of chars) is also being used via a `CollectionView`. last but not the least happy coding :)

Comment: This link is a good tutorial airtle about [wpf data-binding/debugging](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/debugging/) , although it has nothing to do with this question. So i add it here for those who need it.

Comment: This `IsEmpty` property is accesible via the `ICollectionView` for a string `s` via `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(s)`

Comment: So I found this question after wondering the same thing. After playing around for a moment, I saw that ReSharper offered to "Qualify" the accessor, and made this of it: `Path=Text.(componentModel:ICollectionView.IsEmpty)`

Comment: TIL about PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High -- good to know! thank you.

Comment: This is cool and in fact is works fine. But VS 2022 keeps giving me this error "XLS0432 The property 'IsEmpty' was not found in type 'String'.". I can't leave it this way. Any chance to get rid of this error?

Comment: @KarloX, see if this helps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-suppress-compiler-warnings?view=vs-2022