# How to delete the watermark text in the textbox when typing something in the textbox or when adding a text to the textbox in the constructor?

Tags: c#, wpf

The textbox part in the xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="searchBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1100" Height="30" Margin="10,70,0,0" FontSize="16" TextChanged="searchBox_TextChanged">
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="50" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SearchText" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </TextBox.Text>
    <TextBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
            <Grid>
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Hello World" Foreground="LightGray" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </TextBox.Template>
</TextBox>
```

The result is watermark Hello World in the textbox when running the application:

[image: textbox with watermark]

but when in the constructor of the MainWindow.xaml.cs if I'm adding this line:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    searchBox.Text = "aaa";
}
```

I don't see the aaa when running the application in the textbox.

I want that if I add this line in the constructor it will override the Hello World so the Hello World will be deleted and the aaa will be instead.  but it's not showing the aaa at all.

second thing is the event searchBox_TextChanged same here I want when I type something in the textbox the Hello World will be deleted now when I type something it's showing the text I type but also keep the watermark Hello World.

```
private void searchBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Filter the ListView based on the search text
    string searchText = searchBox.Text.ToLower();
    var filteredProcesses = processDictionary.Values.Where(p => p.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchText)).ToList();
    lstvw.ItemsSource = filteredProcesses;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer below:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972726/22732851

Otherwise, you may also set placeholder

```
<TextBox PlaceholderText="placeholderString"/>
```

Comment: Does my answer logic and good?

Answer (score 0):

this is working.

added a new class:

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace wpfMultiThreadListViewUpdate
{
    public class TextLengthToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value is int textLength && textLength > 0)
            {
                return Visibility.Collapsed; // Hide watermark when text is not empty
            }
            return Visibility.Visible; // Show watermark when text is empty
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Updated the xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="wpfMultiThreadListViewUpdate.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpfMultiThreadListViewUpdate"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TextLengthToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextLengthToVisibilityConverter" />
        <!-- Move the Style for ListViewItem outside of ListView -->
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Killed">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="Opened">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- TextBox with Watermark -->
        <TextBox x:Name="searchBox" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1100" Height="30" Margin="10,70,0,0" FontSize="16" TextChanged="searchBox_TextChanged">
            <TextBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="MaxLength" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBox.Style>
            <TextBox.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"/>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="watermark" Text="Your Watermark Text..." Foreground="LightGray" Margin="5,0,0,0"
                           Visibility="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=searchBox, Converter={StaticResource TextLengthToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </TextBox.Template>
        </TextBox>
```

now in the mainwindow constructor I can add a text for example:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    searchBox.Text = "aaa";
    searchBox.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}
```

This will delete the watermark text and will add the aaa instead. or just typing in the textbox(searchbox)  and it will replace the watermark and when deleting the text from the textbox the watermark will show again.