# Adding default / initial text to a Textbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Is it possible to add a "default" text value to a `TextBox` in WPF, with the text disappearing when the user clicks on the control or types anything in it ?

If it's not possible, how would I create a template which allows a user to define a text box with distinct properties for the content of the control and its initial value?

Comment: duplicate question - see here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/833943/76051

Comment: Use water mark for this purpose. Check this link http://windowsclient.net/blogs/swt62/archive/2009/05/10/wpf-textbox-watermark-the-easy-way.aspx and also this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dpatra/WatermarkTextBoxInWPFApplication07272009143315PM/WatermarkTextBoxInWPFApplication.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't familiar with the term. Much appreciated.

Comment: *Simple Solution:* If you just want to add **"add a 'default' text value to a Textbox in WPF"** you can use "SelectedText" property; And for **"text disappearing when the user clicks on the control or types anything in it"**, you can code it in TextChanged event;

Comment: You can use watermark textbox for it.
See the below link:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13406286/how-do-i-set-the-default-text-of-a-textbox-with-a-binding-of-relativesource-self][1]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly possible. You can either:

1) Set the initial text normally, then on an event such as `OnClick()` or `OnTextSelected()` you can delete that text, then it will be blank before they start typing. You can also go one step further and add something to `OnTextChanged()` to see whether the text is blank and every time there is no content, your initial content can be set again.

2) Alternatively, you can create a custom style for your text block, with a text block inside of it, a property to set the text block text and an event hooked up to clear the text block text. This is nicer, but more work. I would recommend this if you wish to re-use this control.

Comment: I think when there would be facility available(watermark) no events needed.

Comment: The watermarking approach is basically the second solution I described, you are applying a style to your textbox =)