# How do I set the default text of a textbox with a Binding of RelativeSource Self

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding

On the initial page load, I am setting it up so that the form is ready to enter a new record.  For some custom data validators, I set the binding to itself.  My question is how can I set the default text to something?

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                 Path="Text"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:MyCustomValidators />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an event handler on the Loaded or Initialized event, and set the Text there.

```
<TextBox Loaded="TextBox_Loaded_1">
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                 Path="Text"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:MyCustomValidators />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And in the code behind :

```
private void TextBox_Loaded_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).Text = "Default text";
}
```

**EDIT:**

XAML only solution :

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Text" Value="Default text" />
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"
                 Path="Text"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="LostFocus" >
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <validators:MyCustomValidators />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: Is it possible to do it in XAML, or am I restricted to code-behind?

Comment: Got it flagged, thanks!  So simple, I don't know why I didn't think of it.