# WPF Forms - how to add text placeholder on textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, forms

I am very new to WPF and C# in general.
I am trying to add a textholder on my textbox, when you focus on the textbox, i want the text to disappear,  and if I move to something else (aka loses focus), and the text is empty, i want the textbox to add the text I want the text back.

but I get error on GotFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);  and  LostFocus.EventHandle(AddText);  on the words "GotFocus" and "Lostfocus"  (on the code below)

what am I missing?

I tried this next code:

```cs
ExcelPath.Text = "Please Drag Excel into here";
ExcelPath.GotFocus += GotFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);
ExcelPath.LostFocus += LostFocus.EventHandle(AddText);

public void RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ExcelPath.Text == "Please Drag Excel into here")
    {
        ExcelPath.Text = "";
    }
}

public void AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ExcelPath.Text))
        ExcelPath.Text = "Please Drag Excel into here";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the syntax for hooking up the event handlers:

```
ExcelPath.Text = "Please Drag Excel into here";
ExcelPath.GotFocus += RemoveText;
ExcelPath.LostFocus += AddText;
```

Get rid of `GotFocus.EventHandle` whatever that is.

Comment: i actually tried that and it didn't work :( .

Comment: Also I the GotFocus.EventHandle because when i was searching for answer, many gave that answer with GotFocus.EventHandle so i tried it... but it didnt work.

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? What happens?

Comment: Hello, today i came with a renew power after banging my head to much yeterday,   it actually worked, i just did something stupid because i guess i was tired. 

it worked,  thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a watermark textbox. You find a lot of it in the internet. For example here: [Watermark / hint text / placeholder TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox)

Or this is also very helpful:
[Create WPF Watermark in Pure XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10687596/create-wpf-watermark-in-pure-xaml)

With this help-links you do not have to try everything by urself.

Comment: its useful, but its mainly XAML in WPF which is a problem for me, I just wanted it code wise on Forms,  and if Forms have XAML i dunno actually where its (as i said i am new, i only saw XAML when i use main window but i dont use it at all)