# Place holder or watermark in TextBox windows 8

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

I want to show a placeholder text in `TextBox` when user hasn't typed anything and `TextBox` is idle.
In Andriod it can be done using  `android:hint="some Text"`
In iPhone it can be done as `textFild.placeholder = "some text";`

How can I do it in windows 8 metro apps?

Thanks

Comment: Windows 8.1 now provides this functionality in the XAML framework itself as PlaceholderText on TextBox.

Comment: @kgiannakakis  [Sergey](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21927164/468724) has already given the answer for 8.1

Comment: I have missed that. I've high-voted it to move it up. It is a good thing you've also edited your answer to include this info.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit for [windows-8.1](/questions/tagged/windows-8.1) they have introduced a new property

```
<TextBox x:Name="UserName" PlaceholderText="User Name"/>
```

Please see [Sergey Aldoukhov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21927164/468724)

---

<strike>For me this is the working solution that I got.</strike>
<strike>If any one has better solution please answer.</strike>

```
private void OnTestTextBoxGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (testTextBox.Text.Equals("Type here...", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        testTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
    }  
}

private void OnTestTextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(testTextBox.Text))
    {
        testTextBox.Text = "Type here...";
    }
}
```

---

<strike>MS also do the same check the [example here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox).</strike>

<strike>**P.S. I have created a custom control for `TextBox` you can download it from [here](https://github.com/rathore619/WatermarkTextBox)**</strike>

Answer (score 8):

In Windows 8.1, TextBox has a PlaceholderText property:

```
<TextBox
    x:Name="UserName"
    PlaceholderText="User Name"
    />
```

Answer (score 6):

The WinRT Xaml Toolkit has a WatermarkTextbox Control: 
http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/

You can get it via NuGet as well, it comes with several other usefull Controls.

you can use it by referncing the toolkit in your Page´s property´s:

```
xmlns:xtk="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
```

And the just access the WaterMarkTextBox like this:

```
<xtk:WatermarkTextBox WatermarkText="some text" />
```

**Edit.:**

Callisto offers a watermark TextBox too: 
https://github.com/timheuer/callisto

Its just not mentioned in the readme yet.

Comment: Note that callisto provides a WatermarkTextbox, too. It's lighter than the WinRT Xaml Tollkit (which is a little bit "heavy" for just a such control).

Comment: Thx i will add it to my answer!

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using WPF, you are looking for a watermark, check out the following stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-textbox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is you can set a default text and clear it using tapped event of textbox or you can use the watermark text box see [here](http://our.componentone.com/2012/08/15/windows-8-xaml-controls-are-here/)