# Windows phone 8 placeholder issue with Windows Phone Toolkit

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone 8 app. I'm new to windows phone 8 development.

I need to add placeholder for text box . I searched in Google & Stack Overflow i got one solution by using The windows phone Toolkit.

I try with following Code.

Step-1: Add Windows Phone Toolkit In Reference By Using Nuget gallery

Step-2: Add namespace in page header

```
 xmlns:xtk="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls"
```

Step-3: My Textbox XAML code

```
<TextBox Name="Usernametxt" Text="User Name"></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="Passwordtxt" Text="Password"></TextBox>
<TextBox Name="Emailtxt" Text="Eamail Address"></TextBox>
```

Step-4: I add the following code under the Usernametxt box [I don't know it's correct or not]

```
<xtk:WatermarkTextBox  WatermarkText="some text" />
```

I got error in above line **The Name WatermarkTextBox does not exist in namespace"using:WinRTXamlToolkit.controls"**

I got this solution  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172170/place-holder-or-watermark-in-textbox-windows-8)

I don't know how to use this property . I need to add placeholder for 4 to 5 textbox in same page.

Help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8.
You need a reference to correct toolkit

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

And then you can

```
<toolkit:PhoneTextBox Hint="some text" Name="Usernametxt" />
```

Make sure you can got the right Nuget package, more details [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/).