# Watermark binding in combobox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

How can I have a watermark before the list of data source or when the textbox is empty.

For example I have something like this:

Select product...
Icecream
Juice
Mouse

This is my xaml

```
 <ComboBox Name="cbProduct" Height="40" Width="200" IsEditable="True"  
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProductsSource}}" 
  />
```

Comment: possibly duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-textbox-in-wpf)

Comment: Mine is combobox. Will it work?

Comment: yep, the solution that @MiklósBalogh linked will overlay a textblock over your combobox. It will work, it's a solution, if you google a bit you will find out some other solutions.