# Windows 8 PasswordBox placeholder

Tags: winforms, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, passwordbox

How to add text placeholder to PasswordBox control in Windows 8 App while it is without text and doesn't get focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no implemented functionality for this and you need to do it yourself.

You can get some idea from [Callisto WatermarkTextBox](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/wiki/WatermarkTextBox)

or from the next question and answers - [Watermark / hint text TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-textbox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 4):

WinRT XAML Toolkit has a [WatermarkPasswordBox](https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/8ed4b738d64c35c85396f431ae20dd36e651d562#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WatermarkPasswordBox/WatermarkPasswordBox.cs) now. You can get it off of [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/winrtxamltoolkit). Also, for Windows 8.1 you can use the PlaceholderText property.