# Change DataContext of specific property inside control - WPF

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datacontext

I have User control which contains TextBox with WaterMark inside

```
<AdornerDecorator>
                        <TextBox 
                            Height="20" 
                            Margin="10,0" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            Text="{Binding MainCategoryTextBoxValue, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Name="MainCatTextBox">

                            <controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>
                                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="MainCategoryTextBlock"> </TextBlock>
                            </controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>
                        </TextBox>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

You can see here WatermarkService implementation
https://stackoverflow.com/a/836463/1548347

I want take "MainCategoryTextBlock" textblock inside `<controls:WatermarkService.Watermark>` and set it DataContext to be same like my UserControl DataContext  in order to change Watermark text in RunTime from my ViewModel.

I tried to bind "MainCategoryTextBlock" DataContext with RelativeSource to my UserControl DataContext but I didn`t succeed (maybe syntax error - Im not sure).

```
DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
```

Do you have any clue how can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be setting the data context property of your window to your view model, and bind the text property of your textblock to your view model property.

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=PropertyOnViewModel} />
```

Comment: I can`t use this approach. I set the datacontext of my view from code behined (my applicatiop based on PRISM). If I will create Instance from my View and do what you suggested I will get 2 instances of my ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

If your UserControl has a name then you can do it like this:

```
DataContext={Binding ElementName="YourUserControlName", Path=DataContext}
```

But i can see that you are using your textbox inside an adorner decorator so you can't use `FindAncestor` in this case because your textbox and your UserControl won't belong to the same visual tree.

Comment: I tried to give my UserControl Name but I get the next message:

Comment: ohh, sorry. Here is the message:
Error 2 : The type name 'Views' does not exist in the type 'DataPresenterModule.DataPresenterModule'.

Meanwhile i solved the problem in other way but I still curios how can i solve it in this way

Comment: @Ofir i can't help you a lot with this information, if your problem has been solved and you still want to talk about my proposed solution then meet me in chat.