# How can I detect when the cursor leaves a Written Textbox using WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, wpftoolkit

I have a text box. I want when user type in it as soon as the cursor leaves the text box, some hidden text fields become visible. How can this be done? Thanks.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-textbox-in-wpf

Comment: [LostFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus.aspx)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 private void TextBox_OnLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        myControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

    }
```

and in your XAML:

```
 <TextBox LostFocus="TextBox_OnLostFocus"></TextBox>
```