# Watermark fontsize/family

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties, adorner

I am currently creating a TextBox with a watermark text and have a little styling problem.
To create the Watermark itself I have included the code explained in here
[Watermark / hint text / placeholder TextBox in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-textbox-in-wpf)
I did not use the accepted answer, but the one with the highest votes. (the one using Adorner)

My textblock looks like this:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="190"
                Padding="16,2,20,2">
        <utils:WatermarkService.Watermark>
            <TextBlock Text="Search" />
        </utils:WatermarkService.Watermark>
    </TextBox>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

Now I face the problem that with this attached property, the textblock in it gets out of scope from my styling I have declared in app.xaml.
The styling looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
    <Setter Property="FontFamily"
            Value="Tahoma" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize"
            Value="8pt"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}" />
</Style>
```

How is it possible to style the textblock within the attached property in app.xaml, preferable with basedon this style so I dont have to declare it serval times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Declare same style for TextBlock` as well `in Application resources`. This way it will be applied to all TextBlocks in your application no matter whether they are part of Adorners or window.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
   <Setter Property="FontFamily"
           Value="Tahoma" />
   <Setter Property="FontSize"
           Value="8pt"></Setter>
   <Setter Property="Background"
         Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE**

If you don't want to duplicate resources, best you can get is use `Label` instead of `TextBlock`. That way you can have style applied on `Control` and can derive styles for `Window` and `Label` from that.

But this won't work for `TextBlock` since it doesn't derive from `Control`.

```
   <Style TargetType="Control" x:Key="BaseStyle">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Tahoma" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="8pt"></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" 
        Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightBrushKey}}"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Window}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}"
           BasedOn="{StaticResource BaseStyle}"/>
```

Then if you use Label inside AdornerDecorator in place of TextBlock, it will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Isnt there an easier way to specify a fontsize/fontfamily thats used default for all text. I kinda hoped its with my styling, but this doesnt seem the case. And I dont like the idea to specify the same styling twice cant I used atleast a basedon style in my case?

Comment: For BasedOn to work targetType should be same for both styles. But in one case you have Window and other is TextBlock.

Comment: So its not possible without duplicate styling?

Comment: Updated with another approach where you can use Label in place of TextBlock where you don't have to duplicate styles.