# Visual Studio WPF UI Designer with Custom Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

This is a bit of a weird question:

I have a custom control that inherits from `TextBox`, and provides "ghost" text - eg it says "Username" in a box until you click inside it, whereupon the "ghost" text disappears, and the user can type in their, in this case, Username.

The "Ghost text" for a control is simply a property in a subclass of TextBox. I then set `TextBox.Text` to it whenever relevant.

In the Visual Studio WPF XAML preview window (the standard UI design one), I would like to be able to "preview" the "Ghost text" - like when you set the actual text of a textbox, you can see it in the preview, not just when you run the application.

I have tried setting the `Text` property to the relevant Ghost text in the `OnInitialised` function, but it doesn't have any effect on the preview.

Where should I be putting code that affects the preview of a control in the designer?

Bonus question: Is there an actual name for what I call "ghost" textboxes? Would be good to know for the future!

Comment: It's called **watermark**.  [for example](http://mahapps.com/controls/textbox.html) and [this one](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20725.wpf-watermarked-textbox-and-passwordbox.aspx)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermark / hint text / placeholder TextBox in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox-in-wpf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an actual name for what I call "ghost" textboxes? Would be god to know for the future!

I have seen this referred to as a "hint" when describing its purpose, or as a "watermark" when describing its appearance.  I tend to employ the former, as it describes the *function*, which is more in line with the WPF design philosophy: the actual presentation is determined by the template, and the conceptual "hint" could be presented differently simply by applying a custom style/template.  Why imply that it should be a watermark when someone could choose to present it in another way?

Design-wise, I think you're approaching this the wrong way.  I would implement this such a way that controls other than a `TextBox` could more easily opt in: use attached properties.

I would create a static class, say `HintProperties`, which declares a couple of attached dependency properties:

- `Hint` - declares the hint content; typically a string, but it need not be.  It could simply be an `object`, akin to the `Content` property of a `ContentControl`.
- `HasHint` - a computed, read-only `bool` property that gets reevaluated when `Hint` changes, and simply indicates whether a control has a `Hint` specified.  Useful as a `Trigger` condition to toggle the visibility of a hint presenter in your control template.

Then, provide a custom style for your `TextBox` (or other control) which overlays a `Hint` presenter atop the regular content, hidden by default.  Add a trigger to reduce the opacity of the hint when the control has keyboard focus, and another to make the hint `Visible` when `Text` is an empty string.

If you really want to go all-out, you can throw in `HintTemplate` and `HintTemplateSelector` properties.

---

However, if this seems like overkill, you can simply declare a `Hint` or `Watermark` property directly on your derived `TextBox` class.  I would not try to implement this by conditionally changing the `Text` property, as that would interfere with data binding and, potentially, value precedence.

Comment: That does sound like a more flexible system - however I fear it is considerable overkill for this project (personal use). I will probably resort to this if I can't find a less complicated solution, though :)

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at using a style with an overlay - it'll give me an excuse to learn more about styles, which I've been neglecting for a while now!

Comment: @hnefatl Agree with Mike.   Check out the second answer [here on this page with the whopping 230 votes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox-in-wpf) for code sample

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a reusable way using a style which you would typically declare in your `App.xaml`. In this style you replace the control template with your own implementation and wrap together some controls. Basically you make up the `WatermarkTextBox` from a normal `TextBox` with a transparent background and place a `TextBlock` control with standard text behind the `TextBox`. The `Visibility` of this `TextBlock` is bound to the `TextBox` using a specific `TextInputToVisibilityConverter` so it will disappear when the `TextBox` has text or just has the focus.

While this maybe looks like a lot of code, you define this once and you can reuse this whereever you need, just by setting style of the `TextBox`

Declaration of some resources

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Converters"
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkBackground" Color="White" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="brushWatermarkForeground" Color="LightSteelBlue" />
<c:TextInputToVisibilityConverter x:Key="TextInputToVisibilityConverter" />
```

Declaration of the style:

```
<Style x:Key="SearchTextBox" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation" Value="None"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="AllowDrop" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid Background="{StaticResource brushWatermarkBackground}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,5" Text="Search..." 
                        Foreground="{StaticResource brushWatermarkForeground}" >
                        <TextBlock.Visibility>
                          <MultiBinding 
                          Converter="{StaticResource TextInputToVisibilityConverter}">
                          <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource 
                                Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}" 
                                Path="Text.IsEmpty" />
                          <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource 
                              Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}" 
                              Path="IsFocused" />
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Visibility>
                    </TextBlock>
                    <Border x:Name="Border" Background="Transparent" 
                       BorderBrush="{DynamicResource SolidBorderBrush}" 
                       BorderThickness="1" Padding="2" CornerRadius="2">

                        <!-- The implementation places the Content into the 
                             ScrollViewer. It must be named PART_ContentHost 
                             for the control to function -->
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" 
                          Style="{DynamicResource SimpleScrollViewer}" 
                          Background="Transparent"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The implementation of the `TextInputToVisibilityConverter`, which just takes text input, converts to bool and converts this to `Visibility`. Also keeps Focus into account.

```
namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class TextInputToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object[] values, 
              Type targetType, object parameter, 
              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (values[0] is bool && values[1] is bool)
            {
                bool hasText = !(bool)values[0];
                bool hasFocus = (bool)values[1];

                if (hasFocus || hasText)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object[] ConvertBack(object value, 
            Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Now all infrastructure is into place. In your view/usercontrol/window just alter the style of the Textbox and there it is, your watermark textbox..

```
<TextBox Style="{DynamicResource SearchTextBox}" />
```