# How to use passchar conditionally in c# login form

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have created a login form where by default it shows text 'enter username' in user name text field when one clicks on password text field and vice versa shows 'enter password' when clicked on username text field

Now I want to use pwd.passchar = "*" here. But password field doesn't shows 'enter password' as text but *****. It should display the text unless user starts typing actual password

Here is my code -

```
public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        if (pwd.Text == "enter password")
        {             
            // Don't show $$ in password text field
        }
        else
        {
            pwd.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
    }



private void textBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        uname.Text = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pwd.Text))
        {
            pwd.Text = "enter password";
        }

    }

private void textBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pwd.Text = string.Empty;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uname.Text))
        {
            uname.Text = "enter username";
```

Please suggest changes...

Comment: What you really want is a "watermark" or "placeholder" text that disappears when the user starts typing. Trying to build this logic around every single textbox is going to be ugly and unmaintainable. You could follow [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/836463/74757) for a way to decorate a text box, *any* textbox, with this functionality, with very little markup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play with empty string for PasswordChar and TextChanged event

in vb.net

```
Private Sub pwd_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles pwd.TextChanged
    If pwd.Text = "enter password" Then
        pwd.PasswordChar = ""
    Else
        pwd.PasswordChar = "*"
    End If
End Sub
```

in c#, probe this

```
    private void pwd_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pwd.Text == "enter password")
            pwd.PasswordChar = Convert.ToChar(0);
        else if (pwd.Text == "")
            pwd.Text = "enter password";
        else
           pwd.PasswordChar = '*'; 
    }
```

Comment: I get error for (I think) the double quotes but then when I use single quotes ie pwd.PasswordChar = ' ', i get error - Empty character literal..

Comment: Since I got my desired result playing with your code. I am going to upvote you answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -

```
if (pwd.Text == "enter password" || pwd.Text == "")
        {
            //Do nothing. Enter Password text will be seen
        }
        else
        {
            pwd.PasswordChar = '*';
        }
```