# How do I create a textbox hint, similar to SO's search box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm creating a login window for a wpf application and for its textbox, what I want to do is the same as how the 'Search Q&A' on the upper right of the Stack Overflow website behaves.

There is a text box containing a text 'Username' and when you focus, the text it will still be displayed, but when you start to type, the text disappear and your input will be displayed. then when you try to erase it back and nothing is in the textbox, it will revert back to the text 'Username'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watermark / hint text / placeholder TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term you are looking for is a **Textbox Hint**

Try this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <VisualBrush x:Key="SearchHint" TileMode="None" Stretch="None" AlignmentX="Left">
        <VisualBrush.Transform>
            <TranslateTransform X="5" Y="0" />
        </VisualBrush.Transform>
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock FontStyle="Italic" Foreground="Black" Opacity="0.3" Text="Search …"/>
            </Grid>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <TextBox VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Height="30">
        <TextBox.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Text" Value="">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SearchHint}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBox.Style>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

## Result:

[image]

Comment: @JulioMotol you're welcome, although its the meaning that you accept and/or upvote the answer if it's correct and been helpful :-)

Comment: but the thing is, it is placed on a grid with a blue background on it and now, the text box also has a blue bg since its on alpha.

Comment: @JulioMotol yup you have to play around and tweak things to your specific needs :-)