# How to set TextBox cursor on the rigth corner of the TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, cursor

How to set `TextBox` cursor on the right corner of the `TextBox`.

[image: Like this:]

While there's a `Text` inside the `TextBox`

Comment: In the attached image cursor is in left

Comment: PlaceHolder is what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HorizontalContentAlignment`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.horizontalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

```
<TextBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: This does not seem related to the question being asked.  `HorizontalContentAlignment` has nothing to do with the cursor position.

Comment: @BrandonKramer Test it and you can see after setting  `HorizontalContentAlignment` to right you see the cursor position in right. See the image in my updated answer. I got this result from the above code.

Comment: But that will also set the Content to the right side, which is not what he asked for.  As far as I can see, he only wants the cursor on the right.

Comment: @BrandonKramer And can you say what's the point of cursor in right side and content in left side? I think it will be meaningless.

Comment: The downvote was because I didn't realize it moved the cursor, so I thought it was not related to the question.  I removed it.  As for the point of this, I have no idea.

Comment: Though, based on his image I agree with NicoRiff, that he seems to be needing a PlaceHolder.

Comment: @S.Akbari just look at the OP pic. What I think he really wants is a PlaceHolder, he just typed right when he wanted to say left :)

Comment: @BrandonKramer The title and the image are saying two different things completely and unfortunately the user is too new to SO to clarify the question, The title says *How to set TextBox cursor on the rigth corner of the TextBox* and the image is about `PlaceHolder`.

Comment: No, I agree with you that it is unclear.  I was just speculating that based on his image he probably is looking for `PlaceHolder` text for an empty text box, rather then trying to move the cursor to the right as the title says.

Comment: @BrandonKramer I even guess that he probably posted a different image from his PC accidentally. Or as Pikoh said *he just typed right when he wanted to say left* or anything else. :-)

Comment: Yeah, the only way we will know is if he edits his question to make it more clear.

Comment: @BrandonKramer yep! im looking for a placeholder. but im doing my own version. because when im searching for a placeholder sample, the codes are too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the Caret position, you have to play with `CaretIndex` property,for example:

```
<TextBox Text="Username" CaretIndex="0"/>;
```

But as @NicoRiff says in a comment, what you probably want is a PlaceHolder. If that's the case, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/833943/579895)