# How to fix Error "XLS0432 The property 'IsEmpty' was not found in type 'String' in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am making a search box and in the process I get an error in the line

Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtSearch, Path=Text.IsEmpty, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"

Specifically under  Path=Text.IsEmpty. I am assuming this error happens because the value of the searchBox will be null at times but I have no idea how to get rid of it.

As long as the error appears I can still compile and run the applicaiton for which I am making the search box but the design of the search box is not what I want. It shows the skeleton for the search box I made instead of the style I made for it called 'txtSearch'.

Comment: A `string` does not have an `IsEmpty` property. What makes you think your Binding Path is valid?

Comment: @Clemens nothing is making me think this, I am fairly new to wpf and so I was trying out a possible way to make a search bar. I don't know what exactly I am doing but am using the microsoft documentation and stack overflow to make progress. I am not  sure how I can make my binding path valid in this case. I can provide more code if that will help answer my quesiton.

Comment: @Clemens, Why are you writing about String? The binding was made to TextBox.Text.

Comment: @zjn , If you are working in WPF, then the error will only be in development mode. At runtime, the TextBox.Text Property will be a CollectionView. And it will have an IsEmpty property. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53362613/13349759 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/59795724/13349759

Comment: Also TextBox.Text, as far as I know, is never null. Even if you explicitly assign null to it, it will contain an empty string.

Comment: @EldHasp thank you so much that was very helpful. Once I saw it was only a cosmetic issue, I looked elsewhere for a possible bug and fixed the issue.

Comment: Be aware that you are relying on a hidden feature of data binding. The type of the Text property is string, i.e. `System.String`, a class that does not have an `IsEmpty` property and that does not explictly implement any interfaces with such a property. The fact that WPF creates a CollectionView for a string just because it is an `IEnumerable` is something that may or may not work in future. I would strictly advise against such usage. The Binding Path is simply not valid. It is also wrong to say that the runtime type of the Text property is CollectionView.

Answer (score 2):

You can control the Visibility of a control based on a TextBox being empty by using [Text.Length](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length) in a DataTrigger:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtSearch" />

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=txtSearch}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=txtSearch}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility"
                            Value="Hidden" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

You could also create a custom `EmptyToHidden` Converter for this which would not require a Style:

```
public class EmptyToHidden : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string strValue &&
            !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strValue))
        {
            return Visibility.Visible;
        }

        return Visibility.Hidden;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: The Convert method should also check that `value` is not null.

Comment: Thank you both for your solutions to help me with this issue I really appreciate it.

Comment: @zjn See my last comment on your question. Using `Text.IsEmpty` as Binding Path is something that works only by accident, and should be avoided. Better use the `Length` property as shown here.

Comment: @Clemens thanks again for the edits, I apologize for the poor C# code, I come from a VB.NET background.