# How to clear TextBox text property in Binding inside a HierarchicalDataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, textbox, datatemplate

I can not clean the text property of a TextBox when the user clicks inside it. The `TextBox` is inside a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` but the trigger doesn't work.

My code is as follows:

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="FoldersTemplate"
                                  DataType="{x:Type vm:FolderViewModel}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <Border>
                <Grid>
                    <TextBox>
                        <TextBox.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Name}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                                        <Setter Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    </Trigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>                                
                        </TextBox.Style>
                    </TextBox>                        
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

[image]

The action I would like to happen is that when the user clicks on the text, it disappears. How can I solve this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Instead of clearing the control, clear the ViewModel's property to which the control is bound.

Comment: Are you maybe looking for a [text box with watermark/hint text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox)?

Comment: Why should `Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"` correspond to `when the user clicks inside it` ??

Comment: @CodingYoshi How can I do it? this is MVVM

Comment: @RandRandom sorry the code is wrong. I should intercept the mousedown event (or something like that) inside the textbox to make sure that if the user clicks in it the text disappears.

Comment: @dymanoid I can not insert other elements inside the template. The mechanism that binds the text property with "name" is very complex