# Net Core: Both Masked Value and Password in TextBox

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, telerik

How do I apply Both a Password and Masked Template in textbox? For example, 
This is a template, as user keeps typing, the numbers (9) will disappear and replaced with star * asterisks, as user types credit card number.

**Ideal Goal:**

[image]

**Current code:**

The Current View below, only shows stars * to begin with, and stars as user keeps typing.

[image]

**TagBuilder:**

```
namespace Web.UI.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement(HtmlTargetElementConts.MaskedTextBox)]
    public class MaskedTextBoxTagHelper : MaskedTextBoxTagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("MaskText")]
        public string MaskText { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("ValueText")]
        public string ValueText { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("IsPassword")]
        public bool IsPassword { get; set; }

        public MaskedTextBoxTagHelper(IKendoHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
        {
        }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {

            this.Mask = MaskText;
            this.Value = ValueText;

            if (IsPassword == true)
            {
                output.Attributes.SetAttribute("type", "password");
            }

            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
<maskedtextbox name="creditcardtest"
                    MaskText="0000-0000-0000-0000"
                    ValueText="9999-9999-9999-9999"
                    IsPassword="true">               
</maskedtextbox>
```

Comment: Why are you using a password field for credit card numbers? Surely you need `IsPassword="false"`?

Comment: its just a customer requirement, didn't decide on it, thanks

Comment: my goal is to show template numbers, and then **** as user keeps typing, not sure password is good terminology, but thats the end goal

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: Can you probably start with `password=false`, display the placeholder and change the `password` to `true` in the `OnChange` handler of the textbox? Also this could be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/833943/watermark-hint-text-placeholder-textbox