# How do I implement a TextBox that displays "Type here"?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

Displaying "*Type here to ...*" until the user enters text into a `TextBox` is a well-known usability feature nowadays. How would one implement this feature in C#?

My idea is to override `OnTextChanged`, but the logic to handle the changes of text from and to "*Type here*" is a bit tricky...

Displaying "*Type here*" on initialization and removing it on first input is easy, but I want to display the message every time the entered text becomes empty.

Comment: is this ASP.NET or windows forms?

Comment: What technology are you interested in? is it ASP.NET, winforms or WPF, and maybe silverlight?
Any way it's called "Watermark textbox" and you can find lots on each of the technologies.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms/4902969#4902969 For future users who look better and updated answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

What you're looking for is a TextBox with a "**watermark**".

There's a sample implementation for C# [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/WaterMark.aspx), all credits to Wael Alghool.

The relevant part of his code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace wmgCMS
{
    class WaterMarkTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private Font oldFont = null;
        private Boolean waterMarkTextEnabled = false;

        #region Attributes 
            private Color _waterMarkColor = Color.Gray;
            public Color WaterMarkColor
            {
                get { return _waterMarkColor; }
                set { _waterMarkColor = value; Invalidate();/*thanks to Bernhard Elbl
                                                              for Invalidate()*/ }
            }

            private string _waterMarkText = "Water Mark";
            public string WaterMarkText
            {
                get { return _waterMarkText; }
                set { _waterMarkText = value; Invalidate(); }
            }
        #endregion

        //Default constructor
        public WaterMarkTextBox()
        {
            JoinEvents(true);
        }

        //Override OnCreateControl ... thanks to  "lpgray .. codeproject guy"
        protected override void OnCreateControl() 
        { 
            base.OnCreateControl();
            WaterMark_Toggel(null, null); 
        }

        //Override OnPaint
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs args)
        {
            // Use the same font that was defined in base class
            System.Drawing.Font drawFont = new System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily,
                Font.Size, Font.Style, Font.Unit);
            //Create new brush with gray color or 
            SolidBrush drawBrush = new SolidBrush(WaterMarkColor);//use Water mark color
            //Draw Text or WaterMark
            args.Graphics.DrawString((waterMarkTextEnabled ? WaterMarkText : Text),
                drawFont, drawBrush, new PointF(0.0F, 0.0F));
            base.OnPaint(args);
        }

        private void JoinEvents(Boolean join)
        {
            if (join)
            {
                this.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.WaterMark_Toggel);
                this.LostFocus += new System.EventHandler(this.WaterMark_Toggel);
                this.FontChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.WaterMark_FontChanged);
                //No one of the above events will start immeddiatlly 
                //TextBox control still in constructing, so,
                //Font object (for example) couldn't be catched from within
                //WaterMark_Toggle
                //So, call WaterMark_Toggel through OnCreateControl after TextBox
                //is totally created
                //No doupt, it will be only one time call

                //Old solution uses Timer.Tick event to check Create property
            }
        }

        private void WaterMark_Toggel(object sender, EventArgs args )
        {
            if (this.Text.Length <= 0)
                EnableWaterMark();
            else
                DisbaleWaterMark();
        }

        private void EnableWaterMark()
        {
            //Save current font until returning the UserPaint style to false (NOTE:
            //It is a try and error advice)
            oldFont = new System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily, Font.Size, Font.Style,
               Font.Unit);
            //Enable OnPaint event handler
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.waterMarkTextEnabled = true;
            //Triger OnPaint immediatly
            Refresh();
        }

        private void DisbaleWaterMark()
        {
            //Disbale OnPaint event handler
            this.waterMarkTextEnabled = false;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, false);
            //Return back oldFont if existed
            if(oldFont != null)
                this.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(oldFont.FontFamily, oldFont.Size,
                    oldFont.Style, oldFont.Unit);
        }

        private void WaterMark_FontChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            if (waterMarkTextEnabled)
            {
                oldFont = new System.Drawing.Font(Font.FontFamily,Font.Size,Font.Style,
                    Font.Unit);
                Refresh();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 45):

Something that has worked for me:

```
this.waterMarkActive = true;
this.textBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
this.textBox.Text = "Type here";

this.textBox.GotFocus += (source, e) =>
  {
    if (this.waterMarkActive)
    {
      this.waterMarkActive = false;
      this.textBox.Text = "";
      this.textBox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
  };

this.textBox.LostFocus += (source, e) =>
  {
    if (!this.waterMarkActive && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.textBox.Text))
    {
      this.waterMarkActive = true;
      this.textBox.Text = "Type here";
      this.textBox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
  };
```

Where `bool waterMarkActive` is a class member variable and `textBox` is the `TextBox`. This probably should be encapsulated though :) There might be some issues with this approach, but I'm not currently aware of any.

I recently discovered that Windows support water marks in text boxes; they are called cue banners (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761639%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). It's very easy to implement:

```
// Within your class or scoped in a more appropriate location:
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

// In your constructor or somewhere more suitable:
SendMessage(textBox.Handle, 0x1501, 1, "Please type here.");
```

Where `textBox` is an instance of `TextBox`, `0x1501` is the code for the windows message `EM_SETCUEBANNER`, the `wParam` may either be `TRUE` (non-zero) or `FALSE` (zero), and `lParam` is the water mark you'd like to display. `wParam` indicates when the cue banner should be displayed; if set to `TRUE` then the cue banner will be displayed even when the control has focus.

Comment: cue banner won't work if you use multi-line textbox.

Comment: This works like a charm on single line TextBox controls. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Based on @Pooven's answer (thank you!), I created this class. Works for me.

```
/// <summary>
/// A textbox that supports a watermak hint.
/// </summary>
public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The text that will be presented as the watermak hint
    /// </summary>
    private string _watermarkText = "Type here";
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the text that will be presented as the watermak hint
    /// </summary>
    public string WatermarkText
    {
        get { return _watermarkText; }
        set { _watermarkText = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether watermark effect is enabled or not
    /// </summary>
    private bool _watermarkActive = true;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets whether watermark effect is enabled or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool WatermarkActive
    {
        get { return _watermarkActive; }
        set { _watermarkActive = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new TextBox that supports watermak hint
    /// </summary>
    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        this._watermarkActive = true;
        this.Text = _watermarkText;
        this.ForeColor = Color.Gray;

        GotFocus += (source, e) =>
        {
            RemoveWatermak();
        };

        LostFocus += (source, e) =>
        {
            ApplyWatermark();
        };

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove watermark from the textbox
    /// </summary>
    public void RemoveWatermak()
    {
        if (this._watermarkActive)
        {
            this._watermarkActive = false;
            this.Text = "";
            this.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Applywatermak immediately
    /// </summary>
    public void ApplyWatermark()
    {
        if (!this._watermarkActive && string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Text)
            || ForeColor == Color.Gray ) 
        {
            this._watermarkActive = true;
            this.Text = _watermarkText;
            this.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Apply watermak to the textbox. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="newText">Text to apply</param>
    public void ApplyWatermark(string newText)
    {
        WatermarkText = newText;
        ApplyWatermark();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
  private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lParam);
  const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501; 

  public Form1()
  {
      InitializeComponent();
      SendMessage(textBox1.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 1, "Username");
      SendMessage(textBox2.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 1, "Password");
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm just starting to learn C# this semester so I'm not an expert, but this worked for me:
(This is using windows forms)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.SelectionStart = 0;  //This keeps the text
    textBox1.SelectionLength = 0; //from being highlighted
    textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
}

private void textBox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.IBeam; //Without this the mouse pointer shows busy
}

private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Equals("Type here...") == true)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}

private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text.Equals(null) == true || textBox1.Text.Equals("") == true)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "Type here...";
        textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**PRODUCES SIMILAR OUTPUT TO HTML WATERMARK**

Here is my code for textbox "watermark" or "preview" text - works great! Using Windows Forms Application.

**NOTE**: This example has 3 text boxes, each has the below method for the "mouse leave" event, and "mouse enter" event respectively.

```
private void textBoxFav_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
  if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text)) {
    textbox.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    if (textbox.Name == "textBoxFavFood") {
      textbox.Text = "Favorite Food";
    }
    else if (textbox.Name == "textBoxFavDrink") {
      textbox.Text = "Favorite Drink";
    }
    else if (textbox.Name == "textBoxFavDesert") {
      textbox.Text = "Favorite Desert";
    }
  }
  else {
    textbox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
  }
}

private void textBoxFav_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  TextBox textbox = (TextBox)sender;
  if (textbox.Text == "Favorite Food" || textbox.Text == "Favorite Drink" || textbox.Text == "Favorite Desert") {
    textbox.Text = "";
    textbox.ForeColor = Color.Black;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the last version of C# the TextBox has the property PlaceholderText, which does all work. So you only need to set "Type here..." as value of this property.

Comment: Think you're gonna need to show us an MSDN link for that one, 'cause I'm having trouble finding anything in the docs to back it up..

Comment: The PlaceholderText property on the TextBox control in Windows Forms is available starting with .NET Core 3.0 or .NET 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Based on answer of Ahmed Soliman Flasha use following class:

```
public class TextBoxHint : TextBox
{
    string _hint;

    [Localizable(true)]
    public string Hint
    {
        get { return _hint; }
        set { _hint = value; OnHintChanged(); }
    }

    protected virtual void OnHintChanged()
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 1, _hint);
    }     

    const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern Int32 SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]string lParam);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the lost focus event and if the property Text is empty, fill it with your default string.

Comment: I also handle the click event to clear the textBox text.

Answer (score 1):

If this is ASP.NET (as opposed to winforms), you could do this:

If you are using jQuery, add this to your document ready (or however you initialize your page):

```
var $textbox = $("textbox selector"); // assumes you select a single text box
if ($textbox.val() == "") {
   $textbox.val("Type here to...");
   $textbox.one('focus', function() {
     $(this).attr('value', '');
   });
}
```

You'll need to do some small refactoring if you are selecting more than one text box (put the if statement inside of an each on the element).

Answer (score 0):

You can draw string "Type here" to the textbox background until it empty

Answer (score 0):

If this is for ASP.NET then you can try [TextBoxWatermark](http://www.asp.net/ajax/ajaxcontroltoolkit/samples/TextBoxWatermark/TextBoxWatermark.aspx).

If this is for Windows Forms, this is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578193/watermark-system-windows-forms-textbox-using-c) in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Why using OnTextChanged?
I would suggest to remove the text "Type here" when the TextBox gets focus.
When the control loses focus and no text is entered, you can display the text again.

Same result and no need for tricky logic.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid control resizing problems and data binding problems and make the code simpler (ok, it is questionable), you can just use a label and toggle it's visibility. Then

```
    private void FilterComboBox_GotFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FilterWatermarkLabel.Visible = false;
    }

    private void FilterComboBox_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!FilterWatermarkLabel.Visible && string.IsNullOrEmpty(FilterComboBox.Text))
        {
            FilterWatermarkLabel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

Another approach for images and also avoiding data binding problems is here
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Joel's answer. I fix his class (thanks for the base!)

```
/// <summary>
/// A textbox that supports a watermak hint.
/// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15232752
/// </summary>
public class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The text that will be presented as the watermak hint
    /// </summary>
    private string _watermarkText;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the text that will be presented as the watermak hint
    /// </summary>
    public string WatermarkText
    {
        get { return _watermarkText; }
        set { _watermarkText = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Whether watermark effect is enabled or not
    /// </summary>
    private bool _watermarkActive;
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets whether watermark effect is enabled or not
    /// </summary>
    public bool WatermarkActive
    {
        get { return _watermarkActive; }
        set { _watermarkActive = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new TextBox that supports watermak hint
    /// </summary>
    public WatermarkTextBox()
    {
        this.WatermarkActive = _watermarkActive;
        this.Text = _watermarkText;
    }

    protected override void OnCreateControl()
    {
        base.OnCreateControl();
        if (this.WatermarkActive)
            CheckWatermark();
    }

    protected override void OnGotFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnGotFocus(e);
        CheckWatermark();
    }

    protected override void OnLostFocus(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLostFocus(e);
        CheckWatermark();
    }        

    public void CheckWatermark()
    {
        if ((this.WatermarkActive) && String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text))
        {
            ForeColor = Color.Gray;
            this.Text = _watermarkText;
        }
        else if ((this.WatermarkActive) && (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.Text)))
        {
            if (this.Text == _watermarkText)
                this.Text = "";
            ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        else
            ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Displaying "Type here to ..." until the user enters text into a TextBox is a well-known usability feature nowadays. How would one implement this feature in C#?

1. Set textbox.text as "Type here to ..."
2. create an event, say **box_click()**
3. -->Put this code in your method

   ```
   private void box_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       Textbox b = (Textbox)sender;
       b.Text = null;
   }
   ```
4. now assign this method to the "Enter" event of your textbox(maybe one or many)