# TextBox with default text value

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms)
>   [How do I fill an empty textbox with default text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178247/how-do-i-fill-an-empty-textbox-with-default-text)

I wish implement a TextBox item in my winform with a default text, like the search textbox in the web *(also like the search in this page, on the top right corner)*, with a gray text that will be erased and replaced when I start to write, or just when I focus on...

Comment: thanks Hans! I didn't know how search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this library:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18858/Fully-themed-Windows-Vista-Controls
(Look at the CueTextBox)

It uses standard Windows API instead of custom drawing. This way yout TextBox will look better on all OS.