# How do I add watermark text to my textBox (e.g. "type here...") in C++ winforms? (Vs2012)

Tags: winforms, textbox, c++-cli, watermark

I was wondering if anyone knew how to add watermark text (e.g. "type here..." in gray writing) to textboxes in visual studio 2012. I've searched the web for a solution to no prevail. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Note: I'm a beginner to C++

Comment: Download [Cue Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27853/CueProvider) and reference that in your C++ project.

Comment: I downloaded it, I tried to reference it to my C++ project though it couldn't read any of the files.

Comment: There are several customized TextBox controls that you can use, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319910/Custom-TextBox-with-watermark and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27849/WaterMark-TextBox-For-Desktop-Applications-Using-C.

Comment: Future hint: the text is called a "placeholder", not a watermark.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I fill an empty textbox with default text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5178247/how-do-i-fill-an-empty-textbox-with-default-text) and [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4902565). This is even easier for you, since no P/Invoke is required in C++/CLI. You can just call the appropriate Win32 APIs directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you don't need any TextBox customizations; you can use events for that. I'd give you the code but **1)** visual studio is giving me problems in c++/cli again and **2)** it would make you a bit lazy as well.

So, I'm going to describe you a way it can be done: assign the foreground color of the `TextBox` as gray (`Color::Gray`, for example) and the text as "type here...". Then subscribe the `TextBox`'s `TextChanged` event, and whenever the text is changed (and different), you should first clear the "type here..." and then change the color to `Color::Black`. If the text is none, you change the color back to `Color::Gray` and the text to "type here...". Pretty simple huh? Yet if you have doubts in the implementation you can ask me by commenting this answer.

Comment: @Daniel, I now notice you said you're a beginner in C++/CLI (I am too), but if you know C#, it should be quite straightforward. Events can often be complicated, but there's plenty of material about that online, and what applies to C# also works in C++/CLI (except for lambdas and such higher-order stuff).

Comment: @Daniel, instead of using the event `TextChanged` you can also use `GotFocus` and `LostFocus`, for a probably simpler logic.