# TextBox for Live Search in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, textbox

How to create a Textbox which displays "search" in grey color when it is empty and standard behavior when user starts typing text into it?

Comment: check this link: http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/2009/01/winforms-autocomplete-textbox-using-c.html

Comment: Try to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms/4902969

Comment: DveExpress WinForm editors (TextEdit) have this functionality built-in already. Can be set through a property called NullText.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do it via TextBox Events **Enter** and **Leave** and Attributes:

```
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox1.Text.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            textBox1.Text = "Search";
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.LightGray;
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to change ForeColor back.

Comment: By the way, this one will clear the textbox every time I reenter on it. It's too hardcore, isn't it?

Comment: @MAKKAM: sharp! I edited the code to prevent user input to be resetted every time the users (re)enters the textbox...

Answer (score 1):

See this thread at MSDN for a possible solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/93a67793-6426-4d4f-be9d-a9b79725efc8