# SendMessage() doesn't work in one project

Tags: .net, marshalling, sendmessage

I tried to use this [Watermark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms/4902969#4902969) it does work correctly on my test project, but it doesn't work in our main project.

How can I debug this? I checked lastwin32error it returns a 0 which I guess is good.

EDIT: It does work in the designer but when I run the project it doesn't.

I created a [connect bug report Link](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/690237/em-setcuebanner-message-not-working-for-old-project) I'm still waiting for some response there...
I uploaded there the project that makes the problem. If I could upload it here too I'll do it.

EDIT: I found that if I set this 2 check boxes then it'll work...
is there a way around it, I don't want to set the 'enable application framework' because it requires a form as the start-up form.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows cue banner, if it's what you're using, has some limitation and requirements.

> You cannot set a cue banner on a multiline edit control or on a rich
>   edit control. To use this API, you must provide a manifest specifying
>   Comclt32.dll version 6.0.

See here for the official details: [EM_SETCUEBANNER message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761639%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

EDIT: The Comctl32 issue means in .NET, you mist ensure there is a `Application.EnableVisualStyles()` line in your program start code, before `Application.Run()`.

Comment: I don't understand how it does work on all new projects I make, but wont work on my old project. its the same control on the same machine.