# How can I set the first line of the combo box, which is connected with a database, empty?

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I set the first line of Combobox empty in my code? 
This is the function that is called when the form loads and it inserts the options on the Combobox.

```
private void preencherComboDpt()
        { carregandoComboDepartamentos = true;

            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection();
            try
            {
                conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);                
                string query = "select * from departamento order by departamento";
                NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(query, conn);                
                cmd.CommandText = query;
                conn.Open();
                NpgsqlDataReader drd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable("tabela");

                dt.Columns.Add("departamento_id", typeof(int));
                dt.Columns.Add("departamento", typeof(string));

                while (drd.Read())
                {

                    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();                    
                    row["departamento_id"] = int.Parse(drd["departamento_id"].ToString());
                    row["departamento"] = drd["departamento"].ToString();
                    dt.Rows.Add(row);                  


                }

                cobUnivDep.DataSource = dt.DefaultView;
                cobUnivDep.DisplayMember = "departamento";
                cobUnivDep.ValueMember = "departamento_id";  


            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error ");
            }
            carregandoComboDepartamentos = false;

        }
```

I already tried inserting the line cobUnivDep.SelectedIndex = null, but it doesn't work.

Comment: try setting cobUnivDep.Selecteditem=null

Comment: `dt.Rows.InsertAt(dt.NewRow(), 0);`. Btw, you can load your DataTable simply with `dt.Load(drd)` (you don't need to add Columns and iterate `DataReader.Read()`). Then, set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties before you set the DataSource.

Comment: Thank you so much. @Jimi It's working :)

Comment: @Jimi do you know how to show "Select an item" on the combo box?

Comment: If you want to show the `Select an item...` thing, then you probably want a `CueBanner` instead of an empty item. See here: [ComboBox Cue Banner not italic when DropDownStyle is DropDown](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904184/7444103), for example. Or here: [Set hint or watermark or default text for ComboBox without adding it as item](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50972125/7444103).

Comment: ...or the extension method (the c# version, just edited) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803179/7444103), so you can just write `comboBox1.SetCueBanner("Select an item...")`