# Adding default value to 0 Index of the Combo Box is not working

Tags: winforms, combobox

I have a code where combo box binding is there.

```
 public static void BindDropDownData(DataTable dtRecords, ComboBox dropDownListId, string textColumnName, string valueColumnName)
        {
            try
            {
                dropDownListId.DataSource = dtRecords;
                dropDownListId.DisplayMember = dtRecords.Columns[textColumnName].ToString();
                dropDownListId.ValueMember = dtRecords.Columns[valueColumnName].ToString();
                dropDownListId.Items.Insert(0, "Select");

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

When I run this code it gives me an error

> System.ArgumentException: 'Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.'

I cannot add dummy -Select- record to the DB. How to handle this?

Comment: Enable the [Cue Banner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8904184/14171304) feature instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a copy of the variable, `DataTable dtRecords`; then, add one record with values `"Select"` and `"0"`.

```
    public static void BindDropDownData(DataTable dtRecords, ComboBox dropDownListId, string textColumnName, string valueColumnName)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSource cloneDataTable = dtRecords;
            cloneDataTable.Insert(0, new DataTable(){ textColumnName = "Select", valueColumnName = "0"});
            dropDownListId.DisplayMember = cloneDataTable.Columns[textColumnName].ToString();
            dropDownListId.ValueMember = cloneDataTable.Columns[valueColumnName].ToString();
            

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```