# How to create a watermark textbox

Tags: winforms, textbox

how to create a watermark text box in winForm

i want to use in my applications login screen

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319910/Custom-TextBox-with-watermark

Comment: thanks david but i dont want to use custom control

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to make it simple, you could do this :

```
  string xyz = "Enter User Name Here.."; 
    private void textBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (textBox.Text.Length.Equals(0))
            {
                textBox.Text = xyz;
            }
        }
    }

    private void textBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (textBox.Text.Equals(xyz))
            {
                textBox.Clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

and do put following lines to your form_load event :

```
    textBox.Text = xyz;
    textBox.Select(textBox.Text.Length, 0);
```