# Make text disappear in textbox on click event, and show the same text again when no focus on it?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, textbox, onclick

I have 6 `Textbox` in a registration form with some preset text.
When I click in the `Textbox` for `Name` then preset text `Enter your full name` should disappear...If I then click on the `Textbox` for `Email` without writing anything in `Name` Textbox, then `Enter your full name` should appear again. This event should happen for all my `Textbox`, but their should be different text in each `Textbox`...Not `Enter your full name` in all of them. Can someone please help me with this?

The code I have right now makes it possible to clear the `Textbox` as I click on them, using GotFocus event.

```
 private void textBox1_GotFocus(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     textBox1.Clear();
 }
```

In the textboxes, I have preset text....I want that exact preset text for each textbox to come back whenever I am clicking outside that `Textbox`.
I've heard something about a "Placeholder" ?

Here's how it looks now with an extra constructor. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
 public partial class CustomTextbox : TextBox
 {
    private const string _text = @"Enter your full name";
    private bool _isEmpty = true;

    public CustomTextbox()
    {

        base.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        Text = _text;
        Leave += LeaveTextBox;
        Enter += EnterTextBox;
        TextChanged += TextChangedTextBox;
    }
    public CustomTextbox(string tempText)
    {

        base.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        Text = tempText;
        Leave += LeaveTextBox;
        Enter += EnterTextBox;
        TextChanged += TextChangedTextBox;
    }
```

Comment: I dont get your exact question but why not repopulate on lostfocus?

Comment: can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I believe you are looking for WaterMark, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a custom Class inheriting from `Textbox`. To achieve this, create a new `Usercontrol`. Delete the base class name and place `Textbox` there. Delete anything in designer if giving compilation error. Build your project. You should see a new control in toolbox. Use it and you are good to go. Here is the code for `Usercontol.cs`

```
public partial class CustomTextbox : TextBox
{
    private const string _text = @"Enter your full name";
    private bool _isEmpty = true;

    public CustomTextbox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        Text = _text;
        Leave += LeaveTextBox;
        Enter += EnterTextBox;
        TextChanged += TextChangedTextBox;
    }

    private void TextChangedTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text);
    }

    public override sealed string Text
    {
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void LeaveTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            Text = _text;
            _isEmpty = true;
            base.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        }
        else
        {
            _isEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    private void EnterTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isEmpty)
            Text = string.Empty;

        base.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
}
```

Let me know if you need any further information. As a not, you can also make `_text` as a public property and use it to set the desired text property.

Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 There would be some issues when setting the Textbox's Text property programmatically, but overall this looks like a decent solution.

Comment: hmmm...good point. Made some changes to reflect your issue. Hope it should work now

Comment: @rapsalands - This works great! Thanks!
But if I would like to have multipel textboxes with the same effect, but different text in each...how do I solve that?

Comment: Read the note in the end of answer. Still I will repeat myself....make _text as public property. Pass a text to set the preset text for the control. Or u can simply pass this text property through constructor and you are done. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have now tried both pass the text through constructor and make _text as public property. None of them give me the result I want.
If I go by the constructor, the text disappears but when losing focus "Enter your full name" comes back? If I try make _text as public property it doesn't work at all. Do you have any other ideas to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem!
Thanks to @rapsalands for providing the code.
I have now modified it for my needs.

```
 public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
 {
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
 }

public partial class CustomTextbox : TextBox
{

    private string defaultText;

    public string DefaultText
    {
        get { return defaultText; }
        set { defaultText = value; }
    }


    private bool _isEmpty = true;


    public CustomTextbox(string myText)
    {

        base.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        this.Text = myText;
        this.DefaultText = myText;
        Leave += LeaveTextBox;
        Enter += EnterTextBox;
        TextChanged += TextChangedTextBox;
    }


    private void TextChangedTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _isEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text);
    }

    public override sealed string Text
    {
        set
        {
            base.Text = value;
        }
    }

    private void LeaveTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
        {
            Text = defaultText;
            _isEmpty = true;
            base.ForeColor = SystemColors.GrayText;
        }
        else
        {
            _isEmpty = false;
        }
    }

    private void EnterTextBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_isEmpty)
            Text = string.Empty;

        base.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText;
    }
}
```

}