# Remove complete text on BackSpace button press of keyboard in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

say i have a text box with readonly properties. It has text in the format 
[my string] i.e enclosed by square brackets.

I want if this textbox is focused and user press backbutton to delete this text, i know it wouldn't be possible as textbox is in readonly mode.

But still on pressing backbutton, Complete text will be delete not one char by one.

Comment: WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET? Always put in tags technology you are using

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to re-invent a cue banner.  Just use the [built-in support](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/17034) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution..

I got it working my self

```
void txt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == '\b')
        {
            TextEdit textBox1 = sender as TextEdit;
            if (textBox1 != null)
            {
                textBox1.Text = "";
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl + A then press back button, it'll do the job,

```
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
tb.SelectAll();
```