# Code for Non-selectable Watermark Text in Textbox in C# windows app

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am currently working on a windows application.

I have already created a watermark Textbox. I just want the watermark text to be non-selectable.

I searching it for a while and i didn't find any thing. All suggesting here is "How to make Watermark TextBox? which I already created"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms)

Comment: Sentences like `Please reply quickly i have to submit my project within 3 days` are often bad perceived by the community. Please ask good questions if you want good answer. Do not expect us to do your job. You should read the [faq], [ask] and http://whathaveyoutried.com pages.

Comment: @SteveB: Sorry I didn't know that. I am new in this field so take care next time & thanks for tip. I am not working in WPF.

Answer (score -1):

Make use of Enter and Leave events of TextBox.