# Toolbox visual studio does not detect a new custom control

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I want to add a new custom control ([Watermark Textbox](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319910/Custom-TextBox-with-watermark)) into my project. I add the dll file as the reference, clean solution, rebuild project. However the watermark textbox still does not appear in the toolbox of the form design. Could you please tell me how to make it available?

Comment: @HansPassant: I have tried to set Toolbox->Automatically Populate Toolbox = true, reset toolbox, clean solution, rebuild project, etc. It doesn't help. I can create the custom control programmatically, but for the form design the custom control does not exist.

Comment: Ah, I see the mistake now, it is because you use a pre-built DLL.  Right-click the toolbox, Choose Items, Browse tab and pick that DLL.  Do beware that this has typical Codeproject quality, it is much simpler and reliable to use the code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/17034).