# How to enable overwrite text in a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm making a program which requires a login system. What I want to do is have a textbox which contains the word 'Username' and when the user clicks it, the 'Username' text is overwritten. For example, Spotify use it on their login screen:

[image]

My question is, how do I do this?

Comment: I'd look into third-party controls like Infragistics.  The out-of-the-box .NET controls can't do this.

Comment: It would be very easy to implement this on a Winform.  Basically, you would set the initial text of the textbox to "Username" with a foreground color of gray. When the user selects the textbox, the text would disappear and the foreground color would turn to black.

Comment: See [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4902565/719186).  It's also called "Cue Banner" or "Ghost Text".

Comment: I think everyone is overthinking this problem. See my answer below.

Comment: @Sylverac Your current solution does not handle the possibility that a user *tabs* into the control.  And what if the user enters the textbox and exits without writing their user name?

Comment: @LarsTech the asker specified that the user clicks the text box. While I agree that you need to code for those considerations, I was merely answering the question he asked. You could also use the `TextBox1.Enter` event if you wanted to handle tabs.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments guys, @LarsTech gave me the answer though. I tried both of the suggestions below but unfortunately none of them worked.

Comment: @JamesAngus What didn't work? I ran that code I provided and it behaved as you explained in your question...

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Text` property of the `TextBox` that you are using for the username to the string `"Username"`. Then, in the `TextBox`'s `Click` event, change it to a blank string. Like so:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

**Edit:**
As @LarsTech mentioned, this does not address if the user tabs into the `TextBox`. If you wanted to account for that too, use the `TextBox`'s `Enter` event instead:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Enter
    TextBox1.Text = ""
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, using `Textbox1.Enter` is the easiest solution. On top you can also catch the case of no text entered via `TextBox1.Leave` like that

```
Private Sub TextBoxLeaveHandle() Handles TextBox1.Leave
    If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
        TextBox1.Text = "Username"
    End If
End Sub
```

Sometimes it can also be useful to use the `TextBox.SelectAll()` function as it not immediately remove the entire text but (obviously from the name) select the entire text so you can overwrite it with your first keypress.