# Add placeholder to textbox control for password c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, placeholder

How to add a placeholder to a c# winform control?

When control lost focus and control text is `null`, I would like the placeholder to appear.

When textbox is `UsePasswordChar true`, It still shows the placeholder (in clear text), and when the user starts to write, it shows password characters.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding placeholder text to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11873378/adding-placeholder-text-to-textbox)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using **WinForms for .NET Core**, or are planning on migrating in the future, you can use the new PlaceholderText property of the TextBox. It greatly simplifies things.

[image: Placeholder]

[image: Password entry]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experienced with WinForms, but I would suspect you could use the `GotFocus` event to change the type to/from password based on whether the control has a value or not.

This should point you in the right direction: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can add events for lostFocus and AddFocus

```
Textbox myTxtbx = new Textbox();
myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";

myTxtbx.GotFocus += GotFocus.EventHandle(RemoveText);
myTxtbx.LostFocus += LostFocus.EventHandle(AddText);

public void RemoveText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     myTxtbx.Text = "";
}

public void AddText(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myTxtbx.Text))
        myTxtbx.Text = "Enter text here...";
}
```

or you can create a new class with a hint, take a look at this answer here:
[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36380881/9615185)

Answer (score 0):

The GotFocus LostFocus doesn't work as intended you will need to set a cue banner.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace PlaceHolderTextBox
{
    public class PlaceHolderTextBox : TextBox
    {
        private string placeholderText = string.Empty;
        private const int EM_SETCUEBANNER = 0x1501;

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern bool MessageBeep(uint type);
        public PlaceHolderTextBox() : base() 
        { 

        }
        [Localizable(true)]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Description("")]
        public virtual string PlaceholderText
        {
            get
            {
                return placeholderText;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value is null)
                {
                    value = string.Empty;
                }

                if (placeholderText != value)
                {
                    placeholderText = value;
                    if (IsHandleCreated)
                    {
                        Invalidate();
                        SetPlaceholderText();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnCreateControl()
        {
            base.OnCreateControl();
            SetPlaceholderText();
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern Int32 SendMessage
      (IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);
        public void SetPlaceholderText()
        {
            SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, placeholderText);
        }
    }
}
```