# How to create a watermark TextBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox, watermark

I found the code in [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms) but it is C# version, so I use http://converter.telerik.com/ to convert the code to VB version, but I still get error......

Error happen on this line:-

SendMessage(Me.Handle, &H1501, DirectCast(1, IntPtr), mCue)

How can I fix it?

> ERROR MESSAGE: BC30311    Value of type 'Integer' cannot be converted to 'IntPtr'.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Class CueTextBox
    Inherits TextBox
    <Localizable(True)> _
    Public Property Cue() As String
        Get
            Return mCue
        End Get
        Set
            mCue = value
            updateCue()
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub updateCue()
        If Me.IsHandleCreated AndAlso mCue IsNot Nothing Then
            SendMessage(Me.Handle, &H1501, DirectCast(1, IntPtr), mCue)   'this line get the error msg
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
        updateCue()
    End Sub
    Private mCue As String

    ' PInvoke
    <DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Unicode)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As Integer, wp As IntPtr, lp As String) As IntPtr
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PInvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage) the right signature in VB.Net for `SendMessage` is :

```
<DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByVal lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Anyway, the problem is in this line:

```
SendMessage(Me.Handle, &H1501, DirectCast(1, IntPtr), mCue)
```

Try to replace it by:

```
SendMessage(Me.Handle, &H1501, New IntPtr(1)), mCue)
```

Comment: thanks, problem solved