# What is it called? textbox with text behind it

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[box with text behind it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxZBR.png)

what is it called in visual studio? it's like textbox but it have an format for that item?

Comment: `Placeholder` is likely what you are looking for -
 https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp Or possibly a `Mask` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/17034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a web application (ASP.NET and HTML) this is called a [**Placeholder**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp). In a Winform application (or WPF) it's called a [**Watermark**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/10f75954-6d14-4926-a02d-98649653b9c8/watermark-textbox-in-winform?forum=winforms). It's used to set a  textbox with a default text (or pattern) which will be erased once the user starts inputting text into it or once it contains a value.

Comment: Mask is another thing. It is usually called "watermark" in winforms\wpf

Comment: @Evk Thanks for the correction.