# how to show in a text field the default or an example of what the user should input vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to set a default value in a text input field which gives the user an example of what to enter. This should be in grey color and should disappear as soon as they start typing.

Comment: Do you mean _Cue Banner_? If so, https://stackoverflow.com/a/59803179/14171304

Comment: @dr.null i think it is... Let me try it out. Thank you for pointing to the right direction

Comment: Maybe [WaterMark Textbox](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/362/Custom-WaterMark-TextBox-for-Windows-Forms-VB-Net.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a placeholder attribute in code behind - if your textbox is

```
<asp:textbox runat="server" ID="mytextbox" />
```

Then in code behind add

```
mytextbox.Attributes.Add("placeholder", "example text")
```

[edit] - sorry, I'm thinking of web forms, not windows forms...

[edit] see here: [Placeholder in TextBox in Window Forms using VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50924572/placeholder-in-textbox-in-window-forms-using-vb-net)