# Initializing properties in custom control and making events

Tags: winforms, events, properties, custom-controls

I created custom control PlaceHolderTextBox with some properties.
Here is my  code:

```
class PlaceHolderTextBox:TextBox
{
    public string PlaceHolderText { get; set; }
    public Color PlaceHolderColor { get; set; }
    public Font PlaceHolderFont   { get; set; }
    public Color StandardColor    { get; set; }
    public PlaceHolderTextBox()
    {
        GotFocus    += OnGetFocus;
        LostFocus   += OnLostFocus;
        TextChanged += OnTextChanged;

        Text      = PlaceHolderText;
        ForeColor = PlaceHolderColor;
        Font      = PlaceHolderFont;

    }
    private void OnGetFocus(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text == this.PlaceHolderText)
        {
            ForeColor = StandardColor;
            Text = "";
        }
    }
    private void OnLostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Text == "")
        {
            ForeColor = PlaceHolderColor;
            Text = PlaceHolderText;
        }
    }
}
```

In designer, i set values:

[image]

And when i start program, i get empty textbox. 
I think reason of that behaviour is that on time constructor executes, the properties are empty, but im not sure.
Also, i want to make events when i change these custom properties.
Is that possible?

Comment: Can you just set the properties you set in the designer in the constructor?

Comment: @jaredbaszler i cant do that because i need to use this control for different usages

Answer (score 0):

Let's first focus on the problem which you are facing. But make sure that you read the ***Note***.

Here is the problem → In constructor, you have set text to the value of `PlaceHolderText` property. At that time, `PlaceHolderText` is empty.

Even if you set a default hard-coded value for `Text` property in constructor, when you drop an instance of your custom textbox on the form, the `InitializeNewComponent` method of the `TextBoxDesigner` will set the `Text` property to empty string. If you close and reopen the designer, your text will appear.

***Note - Why you should not show a placeholder text by setting Text property***

It's definitely not a good idea to implement placeholder feature by setting and resetting `Text` property in `GotFocus/LostFocus` or `Enter/Leave` events, because:

- It will have problems when using data-binding, it will raise validation errors when binding to a number or date property or properties which should be in a specific format.
- When data-binding, if you press Save button, placeholder values will be saved in database unwantedly.
- Based on your code, if user types the same value as you set for placeholder, then when losing focus, you are resetting it to empty. It's wrong.

To have a placeholder(also known as hint, watermark and cue-banner) you can use one of the following solutions: the [native text box feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/3110834) or a [custom paint solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36534068/3110834).

Comment: Also to learn how to create events, follow [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51004518/3110834).

Comment: Let me know if you have any question about the answer.