# How to make events for changing custom made properties (custom control)

Tags: c#, winforms, events, properties, custom-controls

I have custom control inheriting from TextBox class , and i have added some properties , for example i have property placeHolderText and i want to have some event which will occur when i change that text? 
Like these events
[image]

And there is my property in designer view

[image]

How to achieve that?

Comment: Follow C# event pattern.

Answer (score 0):

To create an event in C# you can follow [Standard .NET event patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/event-pattern).

To create a `Changed` event for a `Something` property of a custom control, you can follow these steps:

- Declare an event `SomethingChanged`. It can be any delegate, as a general delegate you can rely on `EventHandler` delegate or `EventHandler<T>`, in case which you want to have a specific event argument rather than using `EventArgs`.
- Create a protected virtual `OnSomethingChanged` method which accepts the event args and is responsible to raising the event. So you should raise the event in body if this method.
- In the property setter, check if the value is different from current value, assign it and call `OnSomethingChanged` to raise the event.

**Example**

```
public EventHandler PlaceHolderChanged;
string placeholder;
public string PlaceHolder
{
    get { return placeholder; }
    set
    {
        if (placeholder != value)
        {
            placeholder = value;
            OnPlaceHolderChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
protected virtual void OnPlaceHolderChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    PlaceHolderChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
}
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any problem applying the solution.