# C# Textbox placeholder transition in Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to to these kind of textbox in windows form ? If yes, How? and can you give me a reference of that in order to achieve this. I've been a front end developer before and it's easy to do on web. I think i'm not the only one who want to know these. Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: This will be very hacky in winforms, its just not designed for a rich UI experience like this. look at wpf or UWP. Though if you have never used it your in for a bit of a learning curve for this type of animation

Comment: I'm not using wpf but i know it's possible in wpf because it's has XML

Comment: Yes WPF and UWP are built for this type of rich UI experience. Winforms is kind of oldshool these days IMO, if this is a fresh project, i would be heading to WPF and be done with it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to a certain extent you can get above animations but it will not be fast or extremely customizable like WPF here are my recommendations:

[Bunifu framework](https://bunifuframework.com/products/bunifu-ui-winforms/)

[Syncfusion](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/windows-forms)

Unfortunately both these are paid frameworks. If I do find a stable free framework I will update this answer.

Also Please Read up on more at [How good can Winforms make a UI look using free resources only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184856/how-good-can-winforms-make-a-ui-look-using-free-resources-only)