# How to make text disappear when textbox is clicked in VS C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

How can I make the text disappear from a textbox when I click on it? (On a windows form using Visual studio 2019 C++)

Comment: Do you want the text to return if the user navigates away without typing anything?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for "Cue Banner" text via the [`EM_SETCUEBANNER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/Controls/em-setcuebanner) window message. See [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/).

Comment: @user4581301 No, I just need for the text to be cleared when the user clicks the textbox

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you could try to use [Control.GotFocus Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus?view=net-5.0). When the textbox gains focus, we could call [TextBoxBase.Clear Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.clear?view=net-5.0)

Here is my code:

```
    private: System::Void textBox1_OnGotFocus(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
    {
        this->textBox1->Clear();

    }
```