# How to implement floating labels in EditBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking for the implementation of `floating labels` in the textbox field using `winforms`.

[image]

All I see on the web is examples in android [Floating Label in Android](https://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-floating-labels-for-edittext/).

I'd like to achieve the same in winforms. Please give me some hints to start with.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36534068/14171304 /  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902969/14171304

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Watermark TextBox in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms)

Comment: @C-PoundGuru Thanks. My requirement is not just to display the watermark. The watermark text has to float to the top of the textbox as I start entering text in the textbox.

Comment: @LakshmanRao Well, you were looking for some "hints to start with". The link above looks pretty good to start. All you're missing is a label that you hide until the text box gets focus.