# How to use watermark System.Windows.Forms.TextBox using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, watermark

I wanna use watermark in Text Boxes of my Windows Form using c#?

I have found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578193/watermark-system-windows-forms-textbox-using-c) in stackoverflow. But I really could not figure out how to use in my windows application.

```
class WatermarkTextBox : TextBox
{
    private const uint ECM_FIRST = 0x1500;
    private const uint EM_SETCUEBANNER = ECM_FIRST + 1;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = false)]
    static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, uint wParam, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lParam);

    private string watermarkText;
    public string WatermarkText
    {
        get { return watermarkText; }
        set
        {
            watermarkText = value;
            SetWatermark(watermarkText);
        }
    }

    private void SetWatermark(string watermarkText)
    {
        SendMessage(this.Handle, EM_SETCUEBANNER, 0, watermarkText);
    }       

}
```

Please help how to use SendMessage Method Or Suggest me any other (easy) way to use watermark.

Comment: It's pretty buggy, try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902565/watermark-textbox-in-winforms/4902969#4902969

Comment: @Hans: :) You are kidding me man.... 148474 reputation....

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a new class [TextBoxWatermarkExtensionMethod](http://pastebin.com/iFzanuC2) into your project and after you can use the method `SetWatermark(string watermarkText)` on your [textbox](http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/2325/testfon.png)

Comment: I needed to use HandleCreated event of TextBox like this: `txtVerificationCode.HandleCreated += (sender, e) => txtVerificationCode.SetWatermark("Paste verification code here");`

Answer (score 0):

You just add a UserControl with this code in your project. `WatermarkTextBox` should appear in your toolbox somewhere. Put it on your form wherever you need the watermarked textbox instead of plain old textbox, set the `WatermarkText` property and you should be ready to go if the code is good.

Answer (score 0):

SetWatermark is an extension method on TextBox, so anywhere on the namespace where the WatermarkTextBox class is added you can use the SetWatermark method passing the watermark string you want to apply on the TextBox like:

```
`myTextBox.SetWatermark("your water mark text here");`
```

SetWatermark will not be visible as public property of TextBox on the designer, but form your code it is accessible just like any of the bult-in methods of a TextBox object.