# How to gray out default text in textbox?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

When I click on a textbox, I want the default text to disappear. Is there any other property that would work for this purpose?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Watermark in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578193/watermark-in-system-windows-forms-textbox)

Answer (score 4):

The following Will set Default text in Gray color. Also When you leave the textbox as blank, again set default text to the textbox.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox2.Enter += new EventHandler(textBox2_Enter); 
        this.textBox2.Leave += new EventHandler(textBox2_Leave);
        textBox2_SetText();
    }

    protected void textBox2_SetText()
    {
        this.textBox2.Text = "Default Text...";
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Gray;
    }

    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.ForeColor == Color.Black)
            return;
        textBox2.Text = "";
        textBox2.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text.Trim() == "")
            textBox2_SetText();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add a method to the `GotFocus` event of the TextBox that will change the Text property to ""

```cs
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    this.textBox1.GotFocus += new EventHandler(textBox1_Focus); 
    this.textBox1.Text = "some default text...";
}

protected void textBox1_Focus(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
    textBox1.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Could you explain me here with example please?

Comment: Where should I put the default text name in above piece of code? When I click the textbox default text should disappear?

Comment: See my edit, just place it on the form load. NOTE that there are more sophisticated ways to accomplish that but I belie that this will be sufficient for you...

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are wanting a Watermark in your Textbox.

See these articles.

- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/319910/Custom-TextBox-with-watermark
- [Watermark in System.Windows.Forms.TextBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578193/watermark-system-windows-forms-textbox-using-c-sharp)
- and if you are using wpf something like this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613590.aspx