# Vb.net Add Placeholder on Custom Text inside Panel

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I created a class that inherit panel and then fill the panel with `Textbox`. Then I try to add a watermark / placeholder in the `Textbox` with this code:

```
Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)
    MyBase.WndProc(m)
    Dim sTxt As String = Me.Text
    sTxt = IIf(sTxt.Length = 0, txt.Text, sTxt)
    If m.Msg = &HF Then
        If Not Me.Focused AndAlso String.IsNullOrEmpty(sTxt) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.WaterMark) Then
            Using g = Me.CreateGraphics()
                TextRenderer.DrawText(g, Me.WaterMark, Me.Font, Me.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, Me.BackColor, TextFormatFlags.Top Or TextFormatFlags.Left)
            End Using
        End If
        MyBase.Update()
    End If
End Sub
```

I tried that code with `Textbox` only and the `WaterMark` does appear, but when I try to use it on my custom text the `WaterMark` never appear. I think the problem is because `WndProc` Event is never triggered because I added a `Textbox` inside the panel. So how can i overrides the `Panel_WndProc` to `Txt_WndProc`?

Comment: Are you talking about a cue banner, i.e. a text prompt that appears in a muted colour in a `TextBox` until you type something into it?  If so then you should make use of the Windows API intended for that specific purpose.

Comment: With that in mind, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18563522/implementing-a-cue-banner-to-a-textbox)